# mTabHost.getTabWidget().getChildAt(4).performClick() dont work in gingerbread

Tags: android, tabwidget

I am making a tab based app. I have to go to the setting tab when the user clicks on the setting button on pop up. The following code is used for that, it works perfectly in ICS but not on gingerbread.

```
mTabHost.getTabWidget().getChildAt(4).performClick();
```

Is there any work around for this?

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
mTabhost.setCurrentTab(4);
```